# PDFKit: How to display generated PDF in browser?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, pdfkit, node-pdfkit

Newbie here. How do I display a pdf generated by PDFKit in another tab using React? I tried following the instructions on their docs but the file is being saved locally -- which is not what I would like to achieve. Here is the code that I found online, and the response that the front end receives.

**routes.js**

```
router.route("/generate-pdf")
  .get(checkIfAuthenticated, generatePDF);
```

**api.js**

```
  static async generatePDF(req, res) {
    const doc = new PDFDocument({bufferPages: true});

    let buffers = [];
    doc.on('data', buffers.push.bind(buffers));
    doc.on('end', () => {
        let pdfData = Buffer.concat(buffers);
        res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(pdfData),
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
        'Content-disposition': 'attachment;filename=test.pdf',})
        .end(pdfData);
    
    });
    
    doc.font('Times-Roman')
         .fontSize(22)
         .text("TEST PDF FILE");
    doc.end();
  }
```

**The response:**

[image]

The API call `console.log`s fine but I would like the file to be opened in another tab. I am confused about how to achieve such feature.

Any leads/hints/suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try removing the header `'Content-disposition': 'attachment;filename=test.pdf'` .  It tells the browser to perform a download instead displaying a file.

Answer (score -1):

you can use embed tag in react and make the data from response as embed tag resource

```
<embed src={`data:application/pdf;base64,${response.data}`}/>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).